# Linq expression multiple left outer join error

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am unable to execute the below linq.

```
   var items(  from p in Patients 
    join q in MURWorksheets on p.PatientId equals q.PatientId into step1
    from s in step1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join t in MURWorksheetAnswers on s.MURWorksheetId equals t.MURWorksheetId into step2


    from s2 in step2.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new {p.FirstName , Date = (s.MURDate == null ? DateTime.Now.Date : s.MURDate),
    s2.MURQuestionnaireId,s2.MURExpctedAnswersId}).ToList();
```

Here is the sql for the same for your reference.

```
select a.FirstName,b.MURDate,c.MURQuestionnaireId,c.MURWorksheetAnswersID from Patients as a
left join MURWorksheet as b on a.PatientId = b.PatientId
left join MURWorksheetAnswers as c on b.MURWorksheetId = c.MURWorksheetId
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: yes using LinqPad

`; expected
Invalid expression term 'in'`

Comment: Are there two errors there "; expected" and "Invalid expression term 'in'"? Can you edit the question and include the code as it is in your class?

Comment: I assume your code is "var items = ..." and not "var items(..."?

Comment: Thanks GrandMasterFlush, if you would have posted in answers , you could have got points. thanks a lot,u r answer camse 1st

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign in your pasted code:

```
var items = (from p in Patients 
    join q in MURWorksheets on p.PatientId equals q.PatientId into step1
    from s in step1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join t in MURWorksheetAnswers on s.MURWorksheetId equals t.MURWorksheetId into step2


    from s2 in step2.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new {p.FirstName , Date = (s.MURDate == null ? DateTime.Now.Date : s.MURDate),
    s2.MURQuestionnaireId,s2.MURExpctedAnswersId}).ToList();
```